# jquery session - dynamic variable naming

Tags: jquery, jquery-session

just having a problem here.
i'm doing the UI of a web-based app using jquery, css.
there's a shopping a cart, and i want to store the selected items in the session, i used jquery.session plugin.
e.g. `var $.session("var1","item1");`

What i want is to dynamically store items into dynamically named variables.
how could i do that?

thanks.

Answer (score 3):

If there's a shopping cart, that data should be handled by a server side scripting language like PHP.  I'm assuming at the end they will be charged via credit card?  This kind of data needs to be secure.

In addition, that's a pretty big part of functionality to be handled by a non-secure client-side language like JS that can be turned off.

Just something to think about in the future..

Answer (score 2):

One way that you could do that is to create a function that stores the 'session' variables.  The session would have two parameters, the variable name and its value.  For example:

```
function setSession(name, value) {

     $.session(name, value);

}
```

Whenever you need to set the jQuery session variable, just call the function as in:

```
setSession('var1', item1);
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use strings to build it up to what you want, like so:

`function storeValueInCart(cartId, value) {
  $.session("var"+cartId, value);
}`

You can also store arbitrary data on elements and use them, like so:

`$(".vote_action").each(function() {
        vote_id = $(this).attr("id").substring("action_".length);
        $(this).data("vote_id", vote_id);
    });`

The above loops through each element with the vote_action class set. On each element it finds it gets the id attribute, which is a string like action_NN, and then chops off the action part.  Then it stores this vote_id as arbitrary data on the element under the "vote_id" name.

Answer (score 0):

Since the session function takes strings as parameters, just create these strings dynamically.

Comment: ah..ok. so, i just need to do "var"+ctr++ outside $.session()?
ok. i see. but how do i retrieve? how do i know the number of session variables i used?... thnx

Comment: According to the jQuery-session-site, there seems there is no way to find out how many, or what key/value-pairs are stored. If you name the keys (first parameter) using incrementing numbers, you could store the max-value in another key/value-pair.