# How to save ajax data with out loosing by clicking on back button?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, zend-framework

I have a set of data on my home page as a result of Ajax response..clicking on any of the data will guide me to another page .but whenever i click the back button of the browser it guides me to the home page , not showing the ajax data..is there anyway to act ajax data as session or something ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [jQuery History Plugin](http://tkyk.github.com/jquery-history-plugin/)

**[Sample Code:](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/history)**

```
function callback(hash) {
    // do stuff that loads page content based on hash variable
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    $.history.init(callback);
    $("a[@rel='history']").click(function(){
        $.history.load(this.href.replace(/^.*#/, ''));
        return false;
    });
});
```

**More Solutions:**

- http://railscasts.com/episodes/175-ajax-history-and-bookmarks
- http://balupton.com/projects/jquery-history
- http://balupton.com/projects/jquery-ajaxy

Answer (score 0):

I would say you should make another call when you click back on home page. By storing on a page with jquery, you are compromising with security. See this [jQSession](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/556350/jquery-session-dynamic-variable-naming). Try to invoke ajax call again since Ajax is fast anyway. All the session data should be handled by a server side script.